# inputing and validating the tax number in java

Tags: java, validation

I want to take the tax number from a user and check if the number that i am getting is correct but i have a problem .When i run the programm if the user first gives a wrong number(a number with less or more than nine digits) i see the message that i wrote which is correct but when the user gives a correct number after some inputs i see the message again and the loop never stops.If anyone can help me i would appreciate it because i'm stuck :)

enter image description here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPEBQ.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code.  Post the code itself, properly formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs when you get the input the 2nd time inside the `while` loop... Beacuse you aren't actually checking again the TIN number.
I advice you to create a function to check if the TIN is valid and use a while loop to continuously get the input

like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Give me your TIN number");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    long TIN = in.nextLong();
    
    
//while the input is not valid ("!" negates the boolean) print invalid input and get the input again
    while(!isValidTIN(TIN)){
        System.out.println("Wrong number! Try Again");
        TIN = in.nextLong();
    };
    // Countinue with your program
    System.out.println("Success");
}

public static boolean isValidTIN(long TIN){
    int count = 0;
    while(TIN > 0){
        TIN /= 10; //You can also use TIN /= 10 instead of TIN = TIN / 10
        count++;
    }
    
    return count == 9;
}
```

Also paste the code next time instead of an image

Comment: Next time, perhaps you should have them paste the code before providing an answer.